# Macros Expected an Expression

Tags: c++, macros

I'm currently working on a school project and the requirements for part of the assignment I am working on looks like this:

> The error state which the client can reference to determine if the
>   object holds a valid date, and if not, which part of the date is in
>   error. The possible error states are integer values defined as macros
>   in the Date class header:

```
NO_ERROR   0  -- No error - the date is valid
CIN_FAILED 1  -- istream failed on information entry
YEAR_ERROR 2  -- Year value is invalid
MON_ERROR  3  -- Month value is invalid
DAY_ERROR  4  -- Day value is invalid"
```

And:

```
void errCode(int errorCode);
```

> This function sets the error state variable to one of the values listed above.

However when I put my code into the second function visual studio gives me a red underline and states "expected an expression" when I try to use the macro values in an if statement.

```
// this code is unfinished and partial

void Date::errCode(int errorCode)
{
    if (errorCode == NO_ERROR) // <- red underline here
    {
        m_errorState = NO_ERROR; // <- red underline here
    }
    if (errorCode == 1)
    {
    }
}
```

The header file defines look like this:

```
#define NO_ERROR = 0        // No error - the date is valid
#define CIN_FAILED = 1      // istream failed on information entry
#define YEAR_ERROR = 2      // Year value is invalid
#define MON_ERROR = 3       // Month value is invalid
#define DAY_ERROR = 4       // Day value is invalid
```

Comment: Remove the equal sign in your macro definition

Comment: Whomever wrote that assignment needs to stop using macros and get on the modern (C++14, C++17) train.

Answer (score 3):

Macros don't require the `=` operator since they're replaced by whatever you've defined for them. In your case, `errorCode == NO_ERROR` would equate to `errorCode == = 0` instead of `errorCode == 0` as you might've expected.

Just drop the equals signs:

```
#define NO_ERROR 0        // No error - the date is valid
#define CIN_FAILED 1      // istream failed on information entry
#define YEAR_ERROR 2      // Year value is invalid
#define MON_ERROR 3       // Month value is invalid
#define DAY_ERROR 4       // Day value is invalid
```

Comment: @QuintonWells Better use an `enum class` instead of macro definitions: `enum class ErrCodes { NO_ERROR, CIN_FAILED, /* ...*/ };`

Comment: @user0042 or even better; `enum class`.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ you don't want to use macros whenever you can avoid them. That's primarily because c-preprocessor macros are merely text replacement and leads to unexpected code results for the unexperienced (or unaware) reader of your code.

The wrong macro defintions you have, lead to text expansion like

```
if (errorCode == = 0)
              // ^^^
```

which of course leads to a syntax error.

---

The correct way to do that in c++ is to use a `enum class` declared inside of your `Date` class (struct):

```
class Date {
public:
    enum class ErrorCodes {
         NO_ERROR = 0        // No error - the date is valid
       , CIN_FAILED = 1      // istream failed on information entry
       , YEAR_ERROR = 2      // Year value is invalid
       , MON_ERROR = 3       // Month value is invalid
       , DAY_ERROR = 4       // Day value is invalid
    };
private:
    void errCode();
    ErrorCodes m_errorState;
};
```

and refer to it like follows:

```
void Date::errCode(Date::ErrorCodes errorCode) {
        m_errorState = errorCode;
}
```